# Jquery - Get the Class Attribute of Current Selector

Tags: jquery

anchor tag has onclick event:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="Gicon Favor" advertid="@item.adID" 
onclick="followadv('@item.adID'); return false;"></a>
```

followad function:

```
function followadv(advertid) {
    if ($(this).attr('class')=="Gicon Favor") {
       alert("Active");
    }
    else{
       alert("Inactive");
    }
}
```

`followad` function is called within lots of `<a>` tag, some of which has the `class='Gicon Favor'`. I am not able to get the class value of the calling element. `$(this).attr('class')` does not work.

Comment: syntax errors.  Last line `});`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** You need to use name value selector as you have not passed reference of clicked element object:

```
$('[advertid="'+advertid+'"]').attr('class')
```

**Solution 2:** For using it with this, you need to modify onlclick event to `onclick="followadv(this)"`:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="Gicon Favor" advertid="@item.adID" onclick="followadv(this)"; return false;"></a>
```

and JS would be:

```
function followadv(this) {
if ($(this).attr('class')=="Gicon Favor") {
   alert("Active");
}
else{
   alert("Inactive");
}}
```

Comment: It's working both with onclick="followadv('@item.adID')" and onclick="followadv(this)".

Answer (score 1):

**Html:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="Gicon Favor" advertid="@item.adID" onclick="followadv(this); return false;">Link</a>
```

**JS:**

```
function followadv(advertid) {
    if ($(advertid).attr('class')=="Gicon Favor") {
       alert("Active");
    }
    else{
       alert("Inactive");
    }
}
```

---

For your code,

```
function followadv(advertid) {
    if ($('[advertid="'+advertid+'"]').attr('class')=="Gicon Favor") {
       alert("Active");
    }
    else{
       alert("Inactive");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you mixing vanilla JS with jQuery?

If you already know the elements that you want to have a click event on (based on the class name), then why not just go for something like;

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="Gicon Favor" advertid="@item.adID"></a>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){

  // make use of the .on() event handler. http://api.jquery.com/on/
  // this will handle a click event on any element that has a class of Gicon
  $(document).on('click', '.Gicon', function(e){
    // prevent the default action of the element. e.g. stop a link from "linking"
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the element's class
    var selectedClass = $(this).attr('class');
  });

});
```

P.S I would probably change the HTML markup to be `data-advertid=` rather than `advertid=` as it keeps it consistent with HTML5 conventions.